# Magento 2 - Add/Remove Sections in admin catalog_product_new for a specific product type

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml

I am trying to modify sections for specific product types.
How can I add or remove sections like "Design" or "Search Engine Optimization"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer I found for deleting sections. New sections can be injected in the same way:

in `adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="product_form_eav" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2000</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

then:

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

Class Eav extends AbstractModifier
{
    /**
     * @var LocatorInterface
     */
    protected $locator;

    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * Eav constructor.
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $meta
     * @return array
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $productType = $this->getProductType();
        if ($productType === \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE) {
            $disabledGroups = ['search-engine-optimization', 'design'];

            foreach ($disabledGroups as $disabledGroup) {
                unset($meta[$disabledGroup]);
            }
        }

        return $meta
    }

    /**
     * Get product type
     * @return null|string
     */
    private function getProductType()
    {
        return (string)$this->request->getParam('type', $this->locator->getProduct()->getTypeId());
    }
}
```