# How do I hide "Search engine Optimization" from product add/edit admin panel?

Tags: magento2, layout, template, uicomponent

As the question states, im simply trying to **hide** the "Search Engine Optimization" [image] from the admin panel, how would I do that? Im not sure whether there's somewhere where id be able to place

```
remove="true"
```

to make it disappear or is there some other way, I've deduced that it comes from the module "module-downloadable" but I cant seem to understand how its rendered or how to **hide** it.

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235035/magento-2-add-remove-sections-in-admin-catalog-product-new-for-a-specific-prod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this in the di.xml to override this segment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="product_form_eav" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Test\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2000</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

And then created the Eav.php file and changed the "modifyMeta" function like so

```
 public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $productType = $this->getProductType();
        if ($productType === Type::TYPE_SIMPLE) {
            $disabledGroups = [
                'search-engine-optimization'
            ];
        foreach ($disabledGroups as $disabledGroup) {
            unset($meta[$disabledGroup]);
        }
    }

    return $meta;
}
```

and I got the names of the segments I needed to remove from the inspect element next to the "data-index" attribute [image]